# Convert Golang unix timestamp to Spark SQL format

Tags: apache-spark

Given a unix timestamp in Nanoseconds, how do you convert to a format compatibile with spark?

It would be helpful if the answer was an UDF (Spark user defined function).

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$

https://github.com/mozilla-services/heka/blob/dev/message/message.proto#L42

Comment: A unix timestamp is compatible with Spark, on Golang side you can represent it with an `int64`, and on spark side you can use a `long` and the `org.apache.spark.streaming.Time` to represent it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this works:

"SELECT cast(t.TIMESTAMP / 1000000000 as timestamp) FROM TABLE t"

t.TIMESTAMP is a big int, timestamp is a type